# how can I add multiple CORS configurations when I want to use my API for 2 different Apps?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-security

My app is meant to be used by normal users and administrators. Because of that, I want to use CORS for the same API with different configurations. Hopefully, the code can help me to explain my idea better.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
{
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000",
                            "https://example.com")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000",
                            "https://admin.example.com")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
        }
```

I need to let the admin subdomain do PUT and DELETE methods but I don't want to let the main domain do it. This is just for security purposes. The admin site is supposed to be able to add and edit the data but the main domain is just to preview it and POST in case of purchase.

I'm not even sure if what I want is possible without creating another backend to connect to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add different @CrossOrigin annotations on different controllers’ methods.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same but I'm looking to do it globally for scalability

Answer (score -1):

You can add multiple configuration like this:

```
registry.addMapping("/admin/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000",
                            "https://example.com")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000",
                            "https://admin.example.com")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");

registry.addMapping("/whatever/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000",
                            "https://example.com")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000",
                            "https://admin.example.com")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
```